# How to print/echo result_array CodeIgniter with looping for (not foreach)

Tags: codeigniter, for-loop

I have function return with `result_array()`

```
public function genJam($id_hari){
        $query  = $this->db->query("SELECT jam FROM mharijam WHERE hari=$id_hari ORDER BY jam");

        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

But, when i use looping for to print/echo this is return blank/not printed

```
for($j=0; $j<count($this->genJam(1)); $j++){
                echo $this->genJam(1)[$j];
                echo "</br>";
            }
```

please help me, thank's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aware that you are calling the function over and over again?

```
$result = $this->genJam(1);
$count = count($result);
if($count)
{
    for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        //$childCount = count($result[$i]);
        //for($j=0; $j < $childCount; $j++)
        //{
            print_r($result[$i]['jam']);
            echo "\n";
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i use multiple looping. but your solution not work, return blank again [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGxZt.png)

Comment: Check your query then .. make sure it is right and its returning results.

Comment: What do you get when you add in var_dump($result); ? Add this after you set $result to see what it's actually returning. This is Debug 101.

Comment: Show us the result of `var_dump($result);` in my code!

Comment: query it's true, have been checked in manual mysql command its returning results

Comment: Its returning an array of arrays, so basically every $result[$j] is an array.

Comment: thanks it's work [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJfhT.png) but, how i can get only value? ex: 08:00:00

Comment: You need to dig deeper using nested loops .. i'll update my code.

Comment: I hope it works, i cannot test it right now, i'm using my phone.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad i didn't notice that the child array consists of key value pairs that's why the above code won't work .. you should use a key instead of $j .. i'll update it again @MuhamamdRizki

Comment: when use `echo print_r($result[$i][$j]);` [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H30cY.png)

Comment: PERFECT! now it's returning value what i want. Thank's very much sir